# Recommendations for a C++ polymorphic, seekable, binary I/O interface

Tags: c++, file-io, polymorphism, iostream, boost-iostreams

I've been using `std::istream` and `ostream` as a polymorphic interface for random-access binary I/O in C++, but it seems suboptimal in numerous ways:

- 64-bit seeks are non-portable and error-prone due to streampos/streamoff limitations; currently using [boost/iostreams/positioning.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/positioning.html) as a workaround, but it requires vigilance
- Missing operations such as truncating or extending a file (ala POSIX `ftruncate`)
- Inconsistency between concrete implementations; e.g. `stringstream` has independent get/put positions whereas `filestream` does not
- Inconsistency between platform implementations; e.g. behavior of seeking pass the end of a file or usage of `failbit`/`badbit` on errors
- Don't need all the formatting facilities of `stream` or possibly even the buffering of `streambuf`
- `streambuf` error reporting (i.e. exceptions vs. returning an error indicator) is supposedly [implementation-dependent](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/exceptions.html) in practice

I like the simplified interface provided by the [Boost.Iostreams Device concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/device.html), but it's provided as function templates rather than a polymorphic class. (There is a [`device` class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/device.html), but it's not polymorphic and is just an implementation helper class not necessarily used by the supplied device implementations.) I'm primarily using large disk files, but I really want polymorphism so I can easily substitute alternate implementations (e.g. use `stringstream` instead of `fstream` for unit tests) without all the complexity and compile-time coupling of deep template instantiation.

Does anyone have any recommendations of a standard approach to this? It seems like a common situation, so I don't want to invent my own interfaces unnecessarily. As an example, something like java.nio.FileChannel seems ideal.

My best solution so far is to put a thin polymorphic layer on top of Boost.Iostreams devices. For example:

```
class my_istream
{
public:
    virtual std::streampos seek(stream_offset off, std::ios_base::seekdir way) = 0;
    virtual std::streamsize read(char* s, std::streamsize n) = 0;
    virtual void close() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class boost_istream : public my_istream
{
public:
    boost_istream(const T& device) : m_device(device)
    {
    }

    virtual std::streampos seek(stream_offset off, std::ios_base::seekdir way)
    {
        return boost::iostreams::seek(m_device, off, way);
    }

    virtual std::streamsize read(char* s, std::streamsize n)
    {
        return boost::iostreams::read(m_device, s, n);
    }

    virtual void close()
    {
        boost::iostreams::close(m_device);
    }

private:
    T m_device;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up going with a set of abstract interfaces similar to what I outlined in the question. There don't seem to be any lightweight, polymorphic standards for this...

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look an Qt's QIODevice class and subclasses? I'm not quite sure if it fits your needs, but maybe its worth a try: [QIODevice](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qiodevice.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I had forgotten about Qt. I don't want to take a dependency on it, but it does provide some perspective.